# Why do I continue to get a datum conflict message even though layers match?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, datum, arcgis-10.6

I have a document with multiple raster layers and a set of buffer zones for which I am trying to use the zonal statistics tool to summarize some of the raster information within the buffers. Most of the layers are in NAD 1983 and so I have projected my 30m DEM layer from WGS84 to NAD83 to match. However, I continue to get "001003: Datum conflict between input and output" warning message when I run the zonal statistics tool along with some other tools.

This is for the buffer layer
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXlrx.jpg

This is for the DEM raster
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TLUA.jpg

I am not sure if I am missing something obvious with the projection, and I have tried re-defining the projection multiple times.

Comment: Re-defining the projection is not the correct procedure for reprojection. Instead of removing previous similar posts and reposting (which can engage automated defenses in the Stack engine), you should heed requests for more information. All you need to do is copy the command parameters and messages from the geoprocessing Results log. Images posted as links are much less likely to get viewed than actual images.

Comment: The 2nd image doesn't have a linear unit which could be your problem. Although there may be common text it may not be recognized as the same, I see this a lot when passing data between systems, even though the name is the same ArcGIS (or the other platforms) don't see them as the same. If you are absolutely sure you know the CRS then by all means define it using ArcCatalog or Define Projection on both but in the CRS dialog search for the correct CRS by its EPSG code like (EPSG:4269 https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/nad83/ ) which will ensure that ArcGIS knows the datum is the same.

Comment: I apologize for my misuse of stackexchange conventions. It seems that the error persists no matter how I define the projection of my layers. I am wondering if it is the lack of a defined vertical coordinate system datum, which exists in the original DEM. Furthermore, I have actually found a version of my DEM that is in NAD83 in its original form and I still get the conflict with the buffer zones. It doesn't prevent me from running zonal tools however.